# Angular 2, error when trying to inject configuration object

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, systemjs

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get ASP.NET server variables into my angular 2 application.  I tried using the window trick, but my app complains that window is undefined.  So, I moved on to try and use systemjs and a main.ts to manually bootstrap my configuration.

To show you what I'm doing, let's start with my config.service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";

export class Configuration {
    BASE_WEB_API_URL: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    constructor(
        @Inject("configuration") private config: Configuration
    ) {
        console.log("Injected config:", this.config);
    }
}
```

Very straight-forward. Next is my app.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ConfigService } from '../../utils/config.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    providers: [ConfigService]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }
}
```

Here, I am allowing DI to handle my ConfigService and declaring a provider.

Next is my main.ts, the bread and butter of this approach.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { Configuration } from "./utils/config.service";

export function RunApplication(baseApiUrl: string) {

    var config = new Configuration();
    config.BASE_WEB_API_URL = baseApiUrl;

    console.log('Configuration setup', config);

    platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: 'configuration', useValue: config }])
        .bootstrapModule(AppComponent);
}
```

Next is the script on my layout page which has systemjs call my main.RunApplication.  This is placed in the header of the page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.26/system.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}}
  });

  System.import('app/main').then(

      (m) => {

          var apiUrl = "@appSettings.BaseUrls.Api";

          m.RunApplication(apiUrl);

        }, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

I'm getting very frustrated because not even the simple window solution works, and I need to get the api url passing through.  I'd appreciate some guidance here on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

EDIT:

I found out if I take the config out of the AppComponent, the compile error goes away, but now I'm getting an error with the systemjs call that is showing in my console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  (app/main.ts)

It's like systemjs cannot find the main endpoint and I'm not sure why.

**EDIT 2**

I think it is my configuration on my systemjs.  My site has a layout like this:

the compiled ts files are in /dist

my index page is in the root

in the folder that holds all my ts files, main.ts is in the app folder

I'm thinking the default systemjs setup I have posted above doesn't know where things are.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your app.component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: require('./app.component.html'),
    providers: [{
        provide: ConfigService ,
        useFactory: (config:Configuration) => {
          return new ConfigService(config);
        },
        deps: [Configuration]
    }]
})
```

You are using the shortcut method for the provider and it may not work in this case.

Edit:

Try this in the bootstrap:

```
platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: Configuration, useValue: config }])
        .bootstrapModule(AppComponent);
```

You need to reference the Configuration class directly in the provide.  It is being messed up by the lowercase and the single quotes.  I just got this to work successfully in my app.

Comment: I tried removing it from the app.component and now systemjs seems to get a 404 when trying to run the endpoint in main.ts.  I am going to try your suggestion, but I fear if systemjs isn't working, then nothing I do will make it work.

Comment: Adding your code, I get "cannot find name config".  I swapped it to `useFactory: (config: Configuration)`, but I'm still getting the error "Error: No provider for Configuration" - likely because systemjs isn't doing what it should be doing

Comment: Yes, I was worried about that.  I don't know how System.js is supposed to be making that config available.  You could just provide it as well.

Comment: The problem is that the values for the config are coming from the server, so they have to be injected somehow.  Every example I have seen is using systemjs to bootstrap in the object for DI.  I'm not sure what you mean by just providing it.

Comment: Actually what you are doing with the parameter to platformBrowserDynamic is giving it an array of providers, so that looks like the right mechanism.  I just haven't used that yet to know why that part might not be working.

Comment: Could be the case on the provider being passed into the bootstrapping. Try it with an uppercase C in Configuration.  I also fixed my backwards parameter.

Comment: Same error, only now it can't find a provider for Configuration.  I suspect it is something with the systemjs config.  It's not even getting to the line where it logs the configuration in RunApplication()

Comment: Got it, I think.  Works in my app.  It was the single quotes on the 'configuration.  Should be the class name Configuration.  That's why it can't find Configuration to provide because it isn't being reference properly in the bootstrap.  Should have seen it sooner, sorry.